# showing something is not poitnwise convergent if it diverges?

Tags: real-analysis

say we had $f_n(x) = (-1)^n$ for $ x \in [0,1/n]$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x \in (1/n,1]$. How would I explain that this is not pointwise convergent? Is it sufficient to say that since taking $n \to \infty$ we get that at $x = 0$ we can have the limit to be either $ 1 $ or $-1$? Similary, what if we had $(-1)^n n $ instead of $(-1)^n$

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to show that a sequence of functions is not convergent at a single point to demonstrate that they do not converge pointwise. So the answer to your question is yes, that is enough.

To argue that $(-1)^n$ diverges, a simple way would be to demonstrate that it has two subsequential limits; $(-1)$ and $1$. A convergent sequence can have only one subsequential limit.

For the sequence $(-1)^n n$, a convergent sequence is a bounded sequence. Thus this is not convergent either.

Comment: What if we had $f_n = 0$ at $x = 0$ and $f_n = (-1)^nn$ for $x \in (0,1/n]$ would this still be non convergent for the same argument?

Comment: That function sequence would converge to the zero function pointwise. For instance, if $x \in (0,1]$, then we know that for some $N$, $1/N < x$. Therefore $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n > N$. At $x=0$, $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ and convergence at that point becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

$f_n(0) = (-1)^n$, and this does not converge.
Same thing for $n(-1)^n$.

On the other hand, it converges almost surely to $0$